# Explicación de como completar NaNs inplace según criterio

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero completar `df['column b']` NaNs inplace siguiendo el siguiente criterio:

```
(df.loc[df['column a']
        .isin(['Foto', 'Impresion Y Entrega', 'Medicina', 'Psicologia Ab1', 
              'Psicologia Profesional', 'Psicologia 1ra Vez', 'Psicologia',
               'Vision', 'Audicion', 'Auditoria']),['column b']]
 .fillna('XXX', inplace = True)
)
```

Encontré esta respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314971/pandas-how-can-replace-work-after-loc

La apliqué:

```
m = df['column a'].isin(['Foto', 'Impresion Y Entrega', 'Medicina', 'Psicologia Ab1', 
              'Psicologia Profesional', 'Psicologia 1ra Vez', 'Psicologia',
               'Vision', 'Audicion', 'Auditoria'])

df.loc[m, 'column b'] = df.loc[m, 'column b'].fillna('XXX')
```

Lo que me llevo al resultado deseado. Pero no puedo (y quiero) entender por que `df.loc[m, 'column b'] = df.loc[m, 'column b'].fillna('XXX')` sobreescribe `df` y, **también**, como es que lo sobreescribe sobre todo `df` si estoy asignando `subset = subset`

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: ahi lo hice, soy nuevo y no me di cuenta que me registre en stack overfloe español

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por partes, al hacer:

```
m = df['column a'].isin(['Foto', 'Impresion Y Entrega', 'Medicina', 'Psicologia Ab1', 
                             'Psicologia Profesional', 'Psicologia 1ra Vez', 'Psicologia',
                             'Vision', 'Audicion', 'Auditoria'])
```

estamos creando un filtro boleano. Por cada valor de la columna (`pandas.Series`) `'column a'` se comprueba si ese valor está en la lista de cadenas pasada como argumento a `isin`. Esto genera otra Serie de la misma longitud e indices que `'column a'` pero en las que los valores son `True` si ese elemento está en la lista de palabras o `False` si no está.

Después tenemos `df.loc[m, 'column b'] = df.loc[m, 'column b'].fillna('XXX')`, la cual dividimos en dos partes:

- `df.loc[m, 'column b'].fillna('XXX')` lo que hace es usar `m` (el filtro boleano) para seleccionar solo las filas en las que el filtro tiene un valor `True`. De esas filas solo toma la columna `'column b'`. 
   Sobre las celdas seleccionadas anteriormente se aplica `fillna`, que retorna una nueva Serie con el resultado.

  Ten en cuanta que tanto NumPy como Pandas permiten usar boleanos para indizar (filtrar):

  > ```
  > >>> ar = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  >
  > >>> ar[[True, False, False, True, True]]
  > array([1, 4, 5])
  > ```
- Obtenida la nueva serie se vuelve a seleccionar las celdas de la columna a modificar usando el filtro con `df.loc[m, 'column b']` y se le asigna (`=`) los valores de la nueva serie retornada por `fillna`.

No se sobrescribe `df` en ningún momento, solo se sobrescriben los valores de las celdas indizadas mediante `df.loc[m, 'column b']`.

Vamos a verlo paso a paso con un ejemplo simplificado:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA": ("foo", "hola", "bar", "python", "foo", "soes"),
                   "ColB": (np.nan, 1.4, 2.5, 7.5, np.nan, np.nan)}
                  )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       ColA  ColB
> 0     foo   NaN
> 1    hola   1.4
> 2     bar   2.5
> 3  python   7.5
> 4     foo   NaN
> 5    soes   NaN
> ```

Ahora vamos a crear un filtro seleccionando solo las celdas de `ColA` que tiene como valor `"foo"` o `"bar"`:

> ```
> >>> filtro = df["ColA"].isin(("foo", "bar"))
> >>> filtro
>
> 0     True
> 1    False
> 2     True
> 3    False
> 4     True
> 5    False
> Name: ColA, dtype: bool
> ```

Observa que podemos indizar usando un iterable de boleanos:

> ```
> >>> df[filtro]
>
> ColA  ColB
> 0  foo   NaN
> 2  bar   2.5
> 4  foo   NaN
>
> >>> df[[True, False, True, False, False, True]]
>
>    ColA  ColB
> 0   foo   NaN
> 2   bar   2.5
> 5  soes   NaN
>
> >>> df.loc[filtro, "ColB"]
>
> 0    NaN
> 2    2.5
> 4    NaN
> Name: ColB, dtype: float64
> ```

Ahora podemos crear una nueva serie usando `fillna` sobre la selección:

> ```
> >>> fill_col = df.loc[filtro, "ColB"].fillna("xxx")
> >>> fill_col
>
> 0    xxx
> 2    2.5
> 4    xxx
> Name: ColB, dtype: object
> ```

Ahora solo quedaria substiruir las celdas del dataframe origina por las de esta serie:

> ```
> >>> df
>      ColA  ColB
> 0     foo   NaN
> 1    hola   1.4
> 2     bar   2.5
> 3  python   7.5
> 4     foo   NaN
> 5    soes   3.3
>
> >>> id(df)
> 139822862171392
>
> >>> df.loc[filtro, "ColB"] = fill_col
> >>> df
>
> ColA ColB
> 0     foo  xxx
> 1    hola  1.4
> 2     bar  2.5
> 3  python  7.5
> 4     foo  xxx
> 5    soes  3.3
>
> >>> id(df)
> 139822862171392
> ```

Comment: Excelente! muchas gracias por la didactica, lo aprecio mucho.